# Fill a HTML table with Javascript values using Parse.com

Tags: javascript, html, parse-platform

I am looking to create a simple HTML website with the data from my iOS app displayed in tables. I use Parse.com for my mobile data, and I will be using Javascript to display it on the website.

I have developed a JSP-based website before, but this time I am using a Javascript plugin for Wordpress, so I cannot use JSP files. Therefore I will need to handle everything in HTML code.

Is there a way to get the following Parse.com query into a HTML table?

```
var GameScore = Parse.Object.extend("GameScore");
var query = new Parse.Query(GameScore);
query.equalTo("playerName", "Dan Stemkoski");
query.find({
  success: function(results) {
    alert("Successfully retrieved " + results.length + " scores.");
    // Do something with the returned Parse.Object values
    for (var i = 0; i < results.length; i++) { 
      var object = results[i];
      alert(object.id + ' - ' + object.get('playerName'));
    }
  },
  error: function(error) {
    alert("Error: " + error.code + " " + error.message);
  }
});
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Create a custom page template for the page you want to show this data on. e.g. create a page called 'score-table' in Wordpress Admin and then create a page template in your theme called 'page-score-table.php'.

Include the parse library scripts in the page and jQuery if you need to (though this should be loaded by Wordpress anyway) and then use something like this.

```
<table id="results-table">
<tr>
  <th>User Name</th>
  <th>Score</th>
</tr>
</table>
```

...

```
<script>
Parse.initialize("Your", "Credentials");

var GameScore = Parse.Object.extend("GameScore");
var query = new Parse.Query(GameScore);
query.equalTo("playerName", "Dan Stemkoski");
query.find({
    success: function(results) {
       for (var i = 0; i < results.length; i++) { 
           var object = results[i];
               (function($) {
                   $('#results-table').append('<tr><td>' + object.get('playerName') + '</td><td>' + object.get('score') + '</td></tr>');
               })(jQuery);
       }
    },
    error: function(error) {
        alert("Error: " + error.code + " " + error.message);
    }
});
</script>
```

[Fiddle showing it HERE](http://jsfiddle.net/richf/sKLxE/), set up a dummy Parse table to show you.

Actually replace the success function with this, I believe append is quite expensive if you have a lot of rows...

```
...
///before query.find();
var myScores='';
...
success: function(results) {
for (var i = 0; i < results.length; i++) { 
  var object = results[i];
  myScores+='<tr><td>' + object.get('playerName') + '</td><td>' + object.get('score') + '</td></tr>';
}
  (function($) {
      $('#results-table').append(myScores);
  })(jQuery);
}
```

Comment: Thank you! I'm going to have a play around and see where I get to!

Comment: Let me know if you need any more help.

Comment: You, sir, are a hero. Thank you so much. I shall learn a lot from this!

Comment: @DevFox I, like nick, need to display Parse data onto a Wordpress page using Javascript. I imported the parse library in my themes footer.php, and used the following example you gave (replacing table names), but I get a blank table on my Wordpress page. Also, I tried displaying an alert after the Parse code, and that does not get called unless I remove the Parse code. Any suggestions?

Comment: @nickjf89 Did you ever get parse data displaying in your Wordpress page?

Comment: @RyanG Hi Ryan, sorry I didn't reply earlier - I've been otherwise engaged following an operation in hospital! Can I suggest you put your code in to a new question and link me to it where I'll be happy to help. Cheers.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26044293/how-to-display-parse-data-in-wordpress-page

Comment: @RyanG Replying to you here as I don't have enough rep to comment on your new question, so annoying!!! Are you getting any errors in your javascript console when running the jquery code?

Comment: @DevFox Yes, this when I try to append a html element: "Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token <". I also get the error when trying to put html tags into a var.